# is that possible to adapt interface in retrofit android?

Tags: android, retrofit2

I try adapting multiple implementation using interface.
For example see the codes below/

*interface or abstract class*

```
interface ChattingJobInterface {
}
```

*data class*

```
@Keep
data class ChattingResponseBody(val chatId: String, val jobs: List<ChattingJobEntity>)

@Keep
data class ChattingJobEntity(val type: String, val data: ChattingJobInterface ?= null)

@Keep
data class ChattingJobWaitEntity(val duration: String): ChattingJobInterface

@Keep
data class ChattingJobEchoEntity(val text: String): ChattingJobInterface

@Keep
data class ChattingJobPlayEntity(val sound: String): ChattingJobInterface
```

*Retrofit Service*

```
    @GET("api")
    fun getTest(): Call<ChattingResponseEntity>
```

*data from server*

```
 var data = {
                code: 'test',
                body: {
                    chatId:'chatId',
                    jobs:[{
                        type:'duration',
                        data:{
                            duration:'duration'
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        type:'sound',
                        data:{
                            sound:'sound'
                        }
                    }]
                }
             }
```

Using interface, I expect retrofit to reflect the interface.
But it is not working.
When I try that, I got this RuntimeException
 `Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: Can't instantiate`

Is there any way to reflect?

Comment: Where are you getting the error please update your code.

Comment: there is no marked line but when I change the interface to class, it's working well.

Comment: I meant how are you using the interface to `instantiate` ?

Comment: I don't understand your meaning. look at the data from server.

Comment: So you were trying to use `ChattingJobInterface` in  place of`ChattingResponseEntity` ?

Comment: yes, for adapting various situation.

Comment: You cannot do that. Use multiple `data class` or return all data in a single request.